# what is the meaning of %< in printf statement?

Tags: awk, printf

i get `</ttd>` instead of `</td>` in the below printf. Can someone please explain why. i want % symbol in my output. But it adds extrac `t` in my output.

```
awk '{printf("<td>%0.2f`%</td>`\n",$0)}'
```

```
bash-4.3$ echo "50" | awk '{printf("<td>%0.2f</td>\n",$0)}'
<td>50.00</td>
bash-4.3$
bash-4.3$ echo "50" | awk '{printf("<td>%0.2f%</td>\n",$0)}'
<td>50.00%</ttd>
bash-4.3$
```

Comment: use **%%** to print a %

Comment: thanks. it works.. please add this answer.. i will accept it

Comment: I get just `%</td>`. No double `t`s.

Comment: The dupe is not an _exact_ duplicate, but the issue and the solution is the same.  It's either that or closing it as "off-topic (typo)".

Answer (score 4):

I can't find any reference of `%<` neither in `man 1 printf` nor `man 3 sprintf` (`man awk` refer to sprintf), however :

In almost every implementation of `printf` (C,awk,php,...) one is to use `%%` to print a single `%` sign.

Comment: There's nothing in [format control letters](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Control-Letters) or modifiers in the GNU awk manual, either.